# Question about a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

About a bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$

If we'll take a line $f(x)=\begin{cases} ax &, x\in\mathbb R\\
0 &, x=\infty  \end{cases}$ then we'll have a bijection.

But about this function: $g(x)=\begin{cases} x &, x\in\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}\\
0 &, x=\infty  \end{cases}$ ? it appears to be a bijection and it's even simpler.

Comment: Your functions are not bijections: $f$ is not $1-1$, since $f(0)=f(\infty)=0$, and $g$ is not defined at $0$.

Comment: What is $a$? What is $l$? Also, what you call a "line" doesn't seem like a line to me.

Comment: Hint: If $\infty$ is sent to $0$, then $0$ better be sent to something other than $0$. What about $1$? And if $0$ is sent to $1$, then $1$ must be sent to something other than $1$. What about $2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is not a bijection, since $f(0)=0=f(\infty)$.

$g$ is not a function from $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$, as $g(0)$ is undefined.

My suggestion for finding a bijection from $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ to $\mathbb R$:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x + 1 & \text{if } x\in\mathbb N_0\\
0 & \text{if } x=\infty\\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$